# C++ "virtual" keyword placement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, syntax, syntax-error, virtual

When I was writing an interface today in Visual Studio 2015 I noticed some weird behaviour. The placement of the "virtual" keyword before a function identifier normally doesn't matter, but if its placed after a pointer or reference, it complains. See the following:

```
class B {};

class A
{
    virtual B fun1a(); // OK
    B virtual fun1b(); // OK

    virtual B& fun2a(); // OK
    B& virtual fun2b(); // ERROR, "expected an identifier"

    virtual B* fun3a(); // OK
    B* virtual fun3b(); // ERROR, "expected an identifier"

    virtual std::unique_ptr<B> fun4a(); // OK
    std::unique_ptr<B> virtual fun4b(); // OK
};
```

Why is this?

And obviously I can avoid the errors completely by always putting the virtual keyword first, but I would've liked to be able to write function definitions the following way:

```
foo const & // return value and relevant keywords on one line
virtual bar( const baz &a ) const // function identifier, arguments, and relevant keywords on another line
{
    /* method implementation */
}
```

Alas, this is not possible for functions returning a reference or pointer...

Is this syntax error language-specific or Visual Studio localized?

Comment: The `&` or `*` in a declaration doesn't go with the type, it goes with the thing you're declaring: `B virtual &fun()` works fine.

Comment: [opinion-based] I'd strongly argue against the syntax you'd "like to write." It looks extremely unfamiliar and confusing. [/opinion-based]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using **trailing return types**? They would allow you to achieve your goal of putting the return type on its own line:

```
#include <memory>

class B {};

class A
{
    virtual auto fun1a()
    -> B;

    virtual auto fun1a() const
    -> B;

    virtual auto fun2a()
    -> B&;

    virtual auto fun2a() const
    -> B&;

    virtual auto fun2ac()
    -> B const&;

    virtual auto fun2ac() const
    -> B const&;

    virtual auto fun3b()
    -> B*;

    virtual auto fun3b() const
    -> B*;

    virtual auto fun3bc()
    -> B const*;

    virtual auto fun3bc() const
    -> B const*;

    virtual auto fun4a()
    -> std::unique_ptr<B>;

    virtual auto fun4a() const
    -> std::unique_ptr<B>;
};
```

The caveat is that if you use `final` or `override`, then you have put them after the return type:

```
virtual auto fun3bc() const
-> B const*
final;
```

Keep that in mind, though, that such a coding convention (putting `final` or `override` on its own line) is highly unusual. Just because C++ allows you to use it, it isn't necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Oh, that's a great idea. Much obliged!

Comment: @Falkgaard: You're welcome. I've added a caveat, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
baz const // return value and relevant keywords on one line
virtual &foo::bar( arg a, arg b ) const // function identifier, arguments, and relevant keywords on another line
{
    /* method implementation */
}
```

Comment: Cheers, that does work. But it feels a bit odd to have the *／&  by the method identifier rather than the return type. Especially if the return value is a pointer. In such a case, I could foresee myself mistakingly (let's say I'm tired) just scanning the first line and expecting the return type to be const baz rather than a pointer. Feels kinda backwards that it doesn't go with the type...

Comment: Generally mandatory fields are kept closest to function prototype.
Virtual is an optional keyword. However return type (here baz&) is a mandatory keyword, which is always required. So in general people keep virtual on the left most side and the return type a little closer to the function signature.